# How to disable RecyclerView item decoration drawing for the duration of item animations

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have some basic item decoration which draws some stuff in `ItemDecoration.onDrawOver` method.

This `RecyclerView` also has `DefaultItemAnimator` set on it.
Animations are working, all is great. Except one thing.

When all existing items are swapped with a new item set in this adapter, the decorations are being shown while animation is running.

I need a way to hide them.
When animation finishes, they need to be shown, but while it is running, they must be hidden.

I tried the following:

```
public void onDrawOver(..., RecyclerView.State state) {
    if(state.willRunPredictiveAnimations() || state.willRunSimpleAnimations()) {
        return;
    }
    // else do drawing stuff here
}
```

but this isn't helping. Decoration is only removed for the short period of animation, but then appears again while it is still running.

*Also setup includes a `RecyclerView.Adapter` which hasStableIds() (in case that bit matters).*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It may depend somewhat on the type of animation you're using, but at least for `DefaultItemAnimator` you need to account for the X/Y translation being done during the animation. You can get these values with `child.getTranslationX()` and `child.getTranslationY()`.

For example, for the vertical case of `onDraw/onDrawOver`:

```
private void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();
    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    final int dividerHeight = mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

    for (int i = 1; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        final int ty = (int)(child.getTranslationY() + 0.5f);
        final int top = child.getTop() - params.topMargin + ty;
        final int bottom = top + dividerHeight;
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}
```

(You may prefer to use `ViewCompat.getTranslationY(child)` if you need to support < API 11.)

Note: for other types of animations, additional adjustments may need to be made. (For example, horizontal translation might also need to be accounted for.)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I was using `view.getLeft()` and `getTop()`. `getX()` and `getY()` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Found an answer myself:

To hide item decorations during an item animation one can simply use this check in `onDraw/onDrawOver`:

```
public void onDrawOver(..., RecyclerView parent, ...) {
    if(parent.getItemAnimator() != null && parent.getItemAnimator().isRunning()) {
        return;
    }
    // else do drawing stuff here
}
```

Comment: Using this approach causes the decorations to disappear for a moment and then reappear after the animation, which I found didn't look as nice as animating the decorations. However, +1 anyway because  `getItemAnimator().isRunning()` is useful information. :)

Comment: @LorneLaliberte yes, I found that unfortunate side effect too. If you find a way around, please share...

Comment: See my answer for an approach that solves this by animating the decorations along with the default animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check child alpha (only for case default animation). If alpha 0 then do nothing