# Making ItemDecoration move with Animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I implemented ItemDecoration into my RecyclerView along with an Animation that plays whenever the RV is loaded. However, I noticed that the decoration appears already at the bounds before the animation completes, and I want to have the decoration move in with the animation at the same time. How would I do this?

So far, I have been entering the animation like so:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerVH recyclerVH, final int position) {
    currentNote = data.get(position);
    final String currentTitle = currentNote.getTitle();
    final String currentContent = currentNote.getContent();
    final int currentPosition = currentNote.getPosition();
    String currentAlarmDate = currentNote.getAlarm();

    Log.d("RecyclerView", "onBindVH called: " + currentTitle);
    Log.d("RecyclerView", "Position at: " + currentPosition + " and Adapter Position at: " + recyclerVH.getAdapterPosition());

    // final Info currentObject = data.get(position);
    // Current Info object retrieved for current RecyclerView item - USED FOR DELETE
    recyclerVH.listTitle.setText(currentTitle);
    recyclerVH.listContent.setText(currentContent);
    Log.d("RecyclerAdapter", "currentAlarmDate is: '" + currentAlarmDate + "'");
    if (currentAlarmDate != null && !currentAlarmDate.equals(" ")) {
        Log.d("RecyclerAdapter", "Current Alarm set for: " + currentAlarmDate);
        recyclerVH.alarm.setText(currentAlarmDate);
    } else
        recyclerVH.alarm.setText(R.string.no_alarm);

    /*recyclerVH.listTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Open new Activity containing note content
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opening: " + currentObject.title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });*/
    runEnterAnimation(recyclerVH.itemView, position);
}


private void runEnterAnimation(View itemView, int position) {
    // Starts Animation

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            position >= lastAnimatedPosition ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
    // If true, up_from_button is loaded
    itemView.startAnimation(animation);
    lastAnimatedPosition = position;
    Log.d("RecyclerAdapter", "lastAnimatedPosition is now: " + lastAnimatedPosition);
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @ernazm Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Are you using the RV item animator? In this case look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061450/how-to-disable-recyclerview-item-decoration-drawing-for-the-duration-of-item-ani)

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: You should provide some code which help us to understand how exactly you have been performing your animation. On the whole `RecyclerView` or on the its items

Comment: @Beloo Added now, any luck figuring it out?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like @Mimmo Grottoli's answer is the closest thing to a solution. Check out this post: [How to disable RecyclerView item decoration drawing for the duration of item animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061450/how-to-disable-recyclerview-item-decoration-drawing-for-the-duration-of-item-ani)

Answer (score -3):

You can read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html)

Or if need to animated decoration you can try this:

https://github.com/slidenerd/materialtest

Thanks, if you not get your solution from it than please ask me i will try my best to give you a better solution. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the documentation does not state exactly how it can perform a 'delayed' decoration. Anything else up your sleeve?

Comment: What do you mean by delayed decoration? Do you mean about lazy loading? Or something else?

Comment: I mean delayed decoration as in having the decoration appear after the animation or with the animation like my original question.